# Resource Manager UI is throwing 500 Internal server Error

Tags: hadoop

I have a cluster with 1 Master and 1 Slave. My Cluster was working fine and suddenly I started to get following error due to which my Resource manager UI is not loading up:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /cluster. Reason:

    INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(URLEncodedUtils.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.ServletUtils.getParameter(ServletUtils.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationHandler.managementOperation(DelegationTokenAuthenticationHandler.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RMAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer2.java:1224)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

If i try to check the daemons running, I can see that RM daemon is running as per:

```
[hadoop@cluster-test hadoop]$ jps
22263 Jps
21549 NameNode
21888 ResourceManager
21733 SecondaryNameNode
```

I also got following error logs in my RM logs but these error does not pop up too often. I am not sure if these issues are related. Thought of sharing here as this might be helpful for people who may take a look at the question:

```
2016-07-05 17:41:49,878 ERROR   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: RECEIVED SIGNAL   15: SIGTERM
2016-07-05 17:41:49,884 ERROR  org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager : ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
```

I am using following hadoop version:

```
Hadoop 2.6.0
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r    e3496499ecb8d220fba99dc5ed4c99c8f9e33bb1
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-11-13T21:10Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
```

Please help as I have been stuck with it for a quite long time and not able to get much help from google.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar problem. The reason may be that some bug in the httpclient jar within hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib.In my case, I accidentally put a higher version of httpclient within that directory which happened to be the buggy httpclient.

Check the following jira for more info:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13215